# php functions stopped working

Tags: php

I have an android app sending some data to a php script. Every time my android service sends that data I receive the following error:

Code:

```
if(isset($_POST['lat']) && isset($_POST['lng']) && isset($_POST['max']))
{
    testMe();

    function testMe()
    {
        echo "asdasddasasd";
    }

    ...
}
```

Error:
05-04 20:05:47.420: D/general(32692): **Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function testMe() in **C:\Apache24\htdocs\myApp\reader\getDistance.php** on line **7**

Why is this wrong?

Comment: Declare the function outside the scope of that if statement.

Comment: I have a feeling that your actual code is different from what you've posted above.

Answer (score 3):

From the [PHP manual documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php):

> Functions need not be defined before they are referenced, **except when a function is conditionally defined** as shown in the two examples below.
>
> When a function is defined in a conditional manner such as the two examples shown. Its definition must be processed prior to being called.

Declare the function before calling it. Try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['lat']) && isset($_POST['lng']) && isset($_POST['max'])) {
    function testMe() {
        echo "asdasddasasd";
    }
    
    testMe();
}
```

Comment: That has some bad code smells, but you're right.

Comment: It might be true in this case, but that's not always the case. See [this demo](https://eval.in/146307). The contents of the entire script is parsed prior to execution. See [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php).

Comment: Yes it usually does work but not inside a `if condition` https://eval.in/146310

Comment: Moral of the story: include your functions/classes at the beginning, not in the middle of nowhere